# email to address not displayed

Tags: android

Here is the code which i used to send email..but TO address string which i have added is not shown on the screen when i run it..didn't get any error..

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"ashwin.innodea@gmail.com"}); // recipients
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message text");
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"ashwin.innodea@gmail.com"});         
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message text");
email.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```